# Data is read-only after inserting it into SQL Server Express table

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a SQL Server Express database. The problem is when I enter data into table I get this message:

> This row was successfully committed to the database.

However, a problem occurred when attempting to retrieve the data back after the commit.

Because of this, the displayed data in this row is read-only.
To fix this problem, please re-run the query

So my data is committed, but it is read-only. Once I reopen my table it is not read-only anymore and I can alter it.

Now, I found that this has to do with fields that have default value defined, and it turns out it is true. I have a field with default value, and if I fill it manually than this problem doesn't occur. But I did not find how to solve this problem without having to fill the field manually, cause I want my field to be filled automatically with the defined default value.

Comment: How are you entering data into the table? Are you using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Yes, I am using SSMS

Comment: It sounds like you're using the "Edit Top 200 Rows" functionality found in SSMS, if this is how you want to interact with your database then you're limited to the functionality programmed by Microsoft. The data itself is not read-only, Microsoft is simply displaying it to you as read-only instead of doing a lookup.

Comment: A SQL Server database is not a spreadsheet. If you want to manipulate data, please learn data manipulation language (insert, update, delete) and do this in a query window.

Comment: I did not know that! Thank you very much @DerrickMoeller